# Convert VS reporting services to XAML

Tags: sql, xml, wpf, xaml, reporting-services

I've created a report in Visual Studio Reporting services that connects to my SQL Database. I'm moving from reporting services to WPF and developing in XAML, I was wondering is it possible to copy XML code from my report onto WPF and it would keep most of it's functionality?

Comment: Take a look to them. You'll see answer is **no** because RDL files has nothing to share with WPF XAML files (well they're both XML but nothing else). What you can do is to host a WinForms report viewer control inside your WPF app.

Comment: @Adriano, you told the question author that they can't do this and then you say that both files are XML... in my mind, that makes it perfectly possible to parse out the report values from the `.rdl` files.

Comment: @user2785177, you're probably better off just retaining the SQL queries and knocking up your own WPF UIs for them as you can do so much more in WPF than you can do with VS Reports.

Comment: @Sheridan for what I understood from his question: "can I take my RDL XML code and paste it as XAML WPF code?". My answer is no because they're just XML but they don't share anything else (like Prolog and C can be written both in text files). If he's asking how he can use them...well yes (2nd part of my comment).

Comment: @Adriano, that's a fair point.